# python socket_io.emit() call from function

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp, python-socketio

I am building a webserver application with aiohttp and python. For the exchange of data I'm using the [socketio](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio) python implementation. For getting data from my frontend to my python script everything works as expected. Now I want to send some data from my python script to display it in the browser. For that reason I want to implement a function that is emitting the given data.

When i try to call `socket_io.emit('data',"test")` directly i get a runtime warning:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncServer.emit' was never awaited > my_server.socket_io.emit('data', "test")
>   RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

I already did some research and this is normal i think.

When i create a async function definiton like this:

```py
async def sendData(dataOut):
    await socket_io.emit('dataOut', dataOut)
```

no message is emitted

---

This is my python testcode:

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio

socket_io = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp')
app = web.Application()
socket_io.attach(app)

app.router.add_static('/', path=str('public/'))


configData = "testConfig"
dataOut ="testOut"
dataBack ="testBack"


async def index(request):
    with open('public/index.html') as f:
        return web.Response(text=f.read(), content_type='text/html')

app.router.add_get('/', index)   

@socket_io.on('connect')
async def connect_handler(sid, environ): 
    print("new connection") # works as expected
    await socket_io.emit('initial_config', configData) # works as expected

@socket_io.on("dataIn")
async def dataInHandler(sid, data):
    print("new data") # works as expected
    await socket_io.emit('dataBack', dataBack) # works as expected

async def sendData(dataOut):
    await socket_io.emit('dataOut', dataOut)  

web.run_app(app, host='XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', port='XXXX')    

sendData(dataOut) #is not doing anything
```

And the "public" HTML file used:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>socketio Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>socketio Test</h1>

        <input type="checkbox" value="0" onClick="emit(id)" id="IN1"></input>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>

            const socket = io("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX");
            function emit(id){
                channel_obj = eval(id)
                console.log(id, typeof(id), channel_obj.value, typeof(channel_obj.value))
                if (channel_obj.value == 1){
                    channel_obj.value = 0
                }
                else{
                    channel_obj.value = 1
                }
                socket.emit("dataIn", id+":"+channel_obj.value);
            }               

            socket.on("initial_config", function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }); 

            socket.on("dataBack", function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }); 

            socket.on("dataOut", function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }); 

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can i create a function that is emitting given data when i call it?

EDIT:

New python script to call the emit function from another thread:

```py
from aiohttp import web
import socketio, threading, time

configData = "testConfig"
dataOut ="testOut"
dataBack ="testBack"
data_flag = 0
connection_flag = 0


print("setup web-server")
socket_io = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp')
app = web.Application()
socket_io.attach(app)

app.router.add_static('/', path=str('public/'))

async def index(request):
    with open('public/index.html') as f:
        return web.Response(text=f.read(), content_type='text/html')

app.router.add_get('/', index)   

@socket_io.on('connect')
async def connect_handler(sid, environ): 
    global connection_flag
    print("new connection") # works as expected
    connection_flag = 1
    await socket_io.emit('initial_config', configData) # works as expected

@socket_io.on("dataIn")
async def dataInHandler(sid, data):
    print("new data") # works as expected
    data_flag = 1
    await socket_io.emit('dataBack', dataBack) # works as expected

async def sendData(dataOut):
    await socket_io.emit('dataOut', dataOut)  

def main():
    global connection_flag
    try:
        print("in main loop")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("wait till a client connects")
        while connection_flag == 0:
            pass
        print("wait 5 seconds")    
        time.sleep(5)
        i = 0
        while True:
            print("now emitting: ", i)
            sendData(i)
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)

    finally:
        thread.join() 
        print("finished, exiting now")

thread = threading.Thread(target=main, args=())
thread.daemon=True 
thread.start()
print("starting web-server")
web.run_app(app, host='192.168.132.210', port='5000')
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start the Server, no Client connected:

```sh
setup web-server
in main loop
starting web-server
======== Running on http://192.168.132.210:5000 ========
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
wait till a client connects
```

2. Connect via browser

```
new connection
wait 5 seconds
now emitting:  0
aiohttp_thread.py:53: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sendData' was never awaited
  sendData(i)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
now emitting:  1
now emitting:  2
now emitting:  3
now emitting:  4
now emitting:  5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the last two lines of your script:

```
web.run_app(app, host='XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', port='XXXX')    

sendData(dataOut) #is not doing anything
```

The `web.run_app()` call is blocking, it starts the web server and then enters a listening state, without ever returning (unless the web server is terminated). So the second line never gets a chance to execute.

So what you need to do is find a better time to call `sendData()`, ideally after one or more clients are connected to the server already. One option is to call it from a client event handler, in your case that would be either the `connect_handler()` or `dataInHandler()` functions. Another option is to start a background task before you start the web server that somehow waits for the appropriate moment to emit the data.

Response to your edit:

You are mixing asyncio and threads, and that does not work. Or actually, you cannot have a SocketIO server in use across threads, all usages must be in the same thread as the asyncio loop. If you need a background task, use a coroutine. The Socket.IO repository has an example of a background task that is started with the `socket_io.start_background_task()` function.

Comment: I noticed that calling emit from an event handler is doing its job fine and also that ```web.run_app()``` is blocking, but when i try to call my ```sendData()``` function from another thread (that is started before i call ```web.run_app()``` and executes the command after the server is started and running) i get the RuntimeWarning mentioned above and my message isn'nt emitted either.
So is there a possibility to trigger an emit from another thread? I noticed you are the developer of socketio for python and may have an answer. I haven't found something regarding this topic in the docs.

Comment: Yes, you can emit from a background thread. The warning that you are showing does not agree with the code that you presented later on, so I'm responding based on the code that you presented. Please update your question with the code that generates that warning.

Comment: Updated the question to demonstrate my problem better

Answer (score 2):

Tanks to Miguel i managed to fix my code, so no threading, instead start a background task with socketio:

```py
from aiohttp import web
import socketio, time, asyncio

configData = "testConfig"
dataOut ="testOut"
dataBack ="testBack"
data_flag = 0
connection_flag = 0

print("setup web-server")
socket_io = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp')
app = web.Application()
socket_io.attach(app)

app.router.add_static('/', path=str('public/'))

async def index(request):
    with open('public/index.html') as f:
        return web.Response(text=f.read(), content_type='text/html')

app.router.add_get('/', index)   

@socket_io.on('connect')
async def connect_handler(sid, environ): 
    global connection_flag
    print("new connection") # works as expected
    connection_flag = 1
    await socket_io.emit('initial_config', configData) # works as expected

@socket_io.on("dataIn")
async def dataInHandler(sid, data):
    print("new data") # works as expected
    data_flag = 1
    await socket_io.emit('dataBack', dataBack) # works as expected

async def sendData(dataOut):
    await socket_io.emit('dataOut', dataOut)  

async def main():
    global connection_flag
    try:
        print("in main loop")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("wait till a client connects")
        while connection_flag == 0:
            pass
        print("wait 5 seconds")    
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        i = 0
        while True:
            print("now emitting: ", i)
            #await sendData(i)
            await socket_io.emit('dataOut', i) 
            i += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    finally: 
        print("finished, exiting now")

socket_io.start_background_task(main)
print("starting web-server")
web.run_app(app, host='192.168.132.210', port='5000')
```